# Subview in UIScrollView doesn't resize according to content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm using Xcode 7.0 and test on iOS 8. Here is my view hierarchy:

- Scroll View

  - Content View

    - Some labels and views
    - Address view

      - A number of Text Fields, ordered vertically

The content view has the following constraints set to the scroll view:

- top,
- bottom,
- leading,
- trailing,
- align center x and
- align center y.

Scroll view's content size is set like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.viewAddress.frame) + kICMarginStandard)];
}
```

The Content view however doesn't get resized to the scroll view's content height, but only to screen height. And even though the scroll view scrolls correctly and my text fields can be seen, they don't receive touch events if I tap on them.

Here is a screenshot where the content is scrolled to the bottom and Content view has red background color. Select country receives touch events, but zip, city and address text fields don't:

[image: Scrolled to bottom]

How can I fix this so all of my text fields work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to set scrollView's contentSize manually since you use autolayout.

All you need is to set constraints properly between scrollView's subviews and add constraints to scrollView's edges, something like:

scrollView.Top-|-contentView.Top-|-subview-|-subview-|-...-|-contentView.Bottom-|-scrollView.Bottom

and the same for left and right edges, so scrollView's content size will be calculated automatically.

Check constraints between subviews twice.

Comment: Thank you. Removing align center y constraint, the setContentSize code and adding bottom constraint between Address and Content views fixed it.